# Manual Triangulation in Point Cloud Library

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I have a point cloud, and I have performed a plane detection. Now I want to triangulate the scene.

I already have the triangulation of each plane, which looks like this :
[image: PlaneTriangulation]

I want to use `Point Cloud Library` `GreedyProjectionTriangulation` in order to reconstruct the scene. So I want to adapt the different functions which intervene in the reconstruction.

I dug in the code of `gp3.h` and `gp3.hpp` (which can be found in `pcl/surface/include/pcl/surface`) and read the associated publication. So far I have come to this :

- Every point of my planes should be marked as fringe at the very beginning - and it is easy to do so with the vector `state_`.
- We add triangles of the planes with the function `addTriangles`, no problem with this.
- I don't know how to enforce the edges. There is a `doubleEdges` vector, but I didn't really understand how it worked. It seems that it is reseted for every iteration on a point.
- I have to push the points of my planes in the `fringe_queue_` vector, but the `addFringe` function is weird, since it asks for 2 arguments and I don't understand why.
- I didn't understand what the vector `part_` was for.

My current result is this :
[image: CurrentResult]

It is not very clear on the image, but since I don't know how to enforce edges, I have issues of overlapping triangles.

*EDIT*

I continue to dig in the code. I identified what the crucial part may be. To avoid a wall of code, you can find the interesting part [here](http://shrimp.xelpaste.com/8055) - it is approximately between line 180 and 285 in gp3.hpp.

I can't understand what `sfn_` and `ffn_` are for. My intuition is that `sfn_[R_]` returns the *second fringe neighbor* of `R_`, and `ffn_[R_]` returns the *first fringe neighbor* of `R_`. So something like this :
[image: sfn & ffn]

If I'm right, I can easily to do this, since I have the contour of my plane sorted in the right order.

I still don't know how to enforce edges of my triangles belonging to my plane. Looking at the code, I think the key is in the `doubleEdges` vector, but I don't know how to modify this part to make it relevant for my problem.

Comment: And if you run one of the existing point cloud triangulation methods directly on your data, will it give some wrong result? Can triangulated planes be added there later?